# MySQL - Find tab stops

Tags: mysql

I have the following data structure in my MySQL dataset:

[image: data with tab stop]

The information behind the tab stop is the level of that address. How can I split this string into two elements? The element before the tab stop and after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can be achieved with the use of SUBSTR but you might be better off splitting that column into two.

```
SELECT 
SUBSTR(street,0,locate('\t',street)),
SUBSTR(street, locate('\t',street)) from your_table
```

Comment: I tried it, the correct format is '\n' what I was looking for - maybe I asked not the correct question ;-) Thanks!

Comment: Glad to have been of some use at least :-)